# Use another column as default value in migration

Tags: sql, knex.js

I am trying to add a new column to existing `tableName` table which has a column `anotherColumn`.

```
exports.up = function (knex, Promise) {
    return knex.schema.table('tableName', table => {
        table.string('newColumn').defaultTo(table.anotherColumn);
    });
};
```

How should I get the value of the existing column into this new column?

Comment: I don't think this will be possible without some `knex.raw` manipulation. What database are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is, you can't: the `defaultTo` value can't come from another column. However, if you're just trying to have the default take place at the time of migration you could do this:

```
exports.up = knex =>
  knex.schema.table('tableName', t => {
    t.string('newColumn')
  })
    .then(() => knex('tableName').update('newColumn', knex.ref('anotherColumn'));
```

It should hopefully be obvious that this will not update new rows being inserted following the migration: for that you'd need a trigger, or to ensure that you covered it in your insert code.

Comment: Thanks! For my case, new rows will be taken care in the insert code.